# Different area values from Zonal Geometry and Tabulate area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, zonal-statistics

[image: Results of Tabulate area and Zonal Geometry; total area are in red]

[image: Tabulate area results]

I am working on Landcover map for Ghana. I calculated the area of each landcover type with Zonal Geometry in ArcMap. Then I wanted to know the area of landcover in each region (as in location). But when I used tabulate area in zonal statistics, the sum of total area for each landcover type among the regions was different from the one I had in using zonal geometry.

Please what could be the cause?

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots / additional information of what difference occur exactly?

Comment: hi Jochen i have edited the post with screenshots

Comment: Perhaps read how zonal geometry assign cell size for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your results look weird because both approaches are using rasters. One would expect similar decimal accuracy.

I did an experiment: converting integer raster to polygon with all environment settings pointing to original raster. I also ran Zonal Geometry as table on original raster. It took awful amount of time to complete and I don't like results:

[image]

Also "thickness" of 8551 m is way off the estimates from both raster and vector approaches:

[image]

So check what cell size is set in your processing environment and if still in doubt, stick to tabulate area results.

Comment: the cell size is default

Comment: This is an issue. Change it to land cover one.